# Danger when using UPS with static

Tags: ups

I just bought a UPS Neo 650A, I managed to install it and it works correctly, but I have a doubt, sometimes I have static and I usually get shocked with the keyboard or the mouse, so if I touch the power button of the UPS to turn it on or off, If I touch it with static to the UPS, can it electrocute me in a dangerous way or burn the UPS?

Comment: `I usually get electrocuted` ... that means that you are now dead ... the word you want is `shocked`

Comment: There is no manual, no installation instructions, or no description how you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common source of electrical leakage currents is from a floating charger floating on the secondary DC.  The Line filter conducts RF noise ~ 1mA to PE gnd.

This current can make you feel from your skin to the metal edge of a laptop if your skin is near a grounded surface ( e.g. socks on some floors)

I suspect your UPS PE gnd is inadequate or you have equipment conducting excess current on PE ground.

Answer (score 0):

Static charge on your body can have a high voltage (thousands of volts) but very little energy.  This can be painful and unpleasant but is generally harmless to humans.  However it can cause damage to electronic circuits, so it’s better to discharge yourself by touching an earthed metal object before handling electronic devices.  If this is a common problem for you, there are various anti-static devices available to mitigate this.